# .toHaveBeenCalledWith Jasmine.objectContaining partial match without naming all keys

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I can't work out of it's possible to check what a function was called with only as a partial match.

I have another test that checks the full passed arguments, but I only want to retest when one piece of data changes.

I want to avoid putting `jasmine.anything()` over and over again, so ideally want to just check for one key in the object that was passed.

The actual code:

```
myThing.add(
    "foo",
    {
        aCheck : true,
        anObject: {}
        aString: "foo",
        aBool: true // I care whether it was passed as true or false
    },
    { another: "object" }
)
```

So my assertion is:

```
    expect(myThing.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      jasmine.objectContaining({
        aBool: true
      })
    );
```

or

```
    expect(myThing.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      jasmine.objectContaining({
        aBool: false
      })
    );
```

I could start adding all the other bits of data but it gets messy:

```
    expect(myThing.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      jasmine.any(String),
      jasmine.objectContaining({
        aCheck : jasmine.anything(),
        anObject: jasmine.any(Object)
        aString: jasmine.any(String),
        aBool: true
      }),
      jasmine.any(Object)
    );
```

But with the amount of data in the object it makes it really hard to debug.

How can I check only partially for the object that is called as the second param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `callFake` that will be called everytime the function is called.

```
spyOn(myThing, 'add').and.callFake((arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
  console.log('myThing.add was called');
  expect(arg2.aBool).toBe(true);
});
```

You can also take advantage `argsForCall` or `mostRecentCall.args`.
http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/